# How to make a code portable?

Tags: android, portability

I am developing an application on Android and this application will be transported on IOS.

My question is simple: how can I make a transportable code? Are there rules to simplify the copy of the code in another language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [java2objc](http://code.google.com/p/java2objc/) - a tool to convert Java code to ObjC code.

You can also try something like MonoTouch (for iPhone) and MonoDroid (for Android), which allows you to develop in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

iOS applications are mostly written in Objective-C.  Android applications are mostly written in Java.  You can't copy the code into another language.  You must port your Android Java code manually to Objective-C/Cocoa-touch.  If your Android application is web based, you can simply re-use the same HTML in a webview.  iOS and Android apps work differently and users expect a different experience, so understanding the differences will help you in creating easily ported code.

Comment: Thank you, I know I must rewrite the code, but I just want to know if there are some rule to make it easier.